# Using JS .split and join with an array multiple times. It only runs the last pair

Tags: javascript, join, replace, split

I'm trying to use JS to parse a text input field on keyup, to show the same text with all the pronouns changed. It should read: I, me, mine and produce:
you, you, yours
s/he, s/he, hers/his
they, them, theirs

It works perfectly for the first set of replacements. On the second and third sets it only replaces the last variable set in the array. :(

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to write this code. I've made each section completely duplicative trying to solve my problem to no available.  I fear I'm making a simple mistake.

Here's a fiddle if you'd like to take a pass at it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8k9b83mo/3/

Here's the raw JS:

```
function grammar() {

    text = ' ' + document.getElementById("first_p").value + ' ';
    var array = {
        " my ": " your ",
        " myself ": " yourself ",
        " mine ": " yours ",
        " I ": " you ",
        " me ": " you ",
        " our ": " your "
    };
    for (var val in array)
        text = text.split(val).join(array[val]);
    document.getElementById('2_pe').innerHTML = text;

    text2 = ' ' + document.getElementById("first_p").value + ' ';
    var array2 = {
        " my ": " her/his ",
        " myself ": " herself/himself ",
        " mine ": " hers/his ",
        " I ": " s/he ",
        " me ": " s/he ",
        " our ": " her/his "
    };
    for (var val2 in array2)
        text_3pe1 = text2.split(val2).join(array2[val2]);
    document.getElementById('3_pe1').innerHTML = text_3pe1;

    text3 = ' ' + document.getElementById("first_p").value + ' ';
    var array3 = {
        " my ": " their ",
        " myself ": " themself ",
        " mine ": " theirs ",
        " I ": " they ",
        " me ": " they ",
        " our ": " their "
    };
    for (var val3 in array3)
        text_3pe2 = text3.split(val3).join(array3[val3]);
    document.getElementById('3_pe2').innerHTML = text_3pe2;

}
```

Thanks so much for your help! I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Those are not arrays. They're objects. Arrays in JavaScript refer to instances of the Array constructor, which have some special behavior around numerically-indexed properties.

Comment: All of those local variables should be declared with `var`.

Comment: Thanks Pointy. I'm struggling to self teach JS after self teaching PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the wrong variables in your forEach methods

change the following lines :

```
text_3pe1 = text2.split(val2).join(array2[val2]);
document.getElementById('3_pe1').innerHTML = text_3pe1;

text_3pe2 = text3.split(val3).join(array3[val3]);
document.getElementById('3_pe2').innerHTML = text_3pe2;
```

for

```
text2= text2.split(val2).join(array2[val2]);
document.getElementById('3_pe1').innerHTML = text2;

text3= text3.split(val3).join(array3[val3]);
document.getElementById('3_pe2').innerHTML = text3;
```

it was doing the substitutions, just in the wrong place.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ucpfL2bs/

Answer (score 2):

You aren't updating `text2` and `text3` each time through the for loop, so only the last changes are saved to `text_3pe1` and `text_3pe2`. Replace `text_3pe1` with `text2` and `text_3pe2` with `text3`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/znr06cue/), and you should get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you are not updating the correct variables in your for loops. However I think you should reconsider your approach a bit. Right now you're splitting and joining on every iteration of the loop which is a bit unnecessary.

This approach allows you to reduce your similar code and replaces the words in a temporary array and joins back once:

```
function grammar() {
    replace(document.getElementById('first_p').value, {
        "my": "your",
            "myself": "yourself",
            "mine": "yours",
            "I": "you",
            "me": "you",
            "our": "your"
    }, document.getElementById('2_pe'));

    replace(document.getElementById('first_p').value, {
        "my": "her/his",
            "myself": "herself/himself",
            "mine": "hers/his",
            "I": "s/he",
            "me": "s/he",
            "our": "her/his"
    }, document.getElementById('3_pe1'));

    replace(document.getElementById('first_p').value, {
        "my": "their",
            "myself": "themself",
            "mine": "theirs",
            "I": "they",
            "me": "they",
            "our": "their"
    }, document.getElementById('3_pe2'));
}

function replace(inputText, replacements, displayElement) {
    var words = inputText.split(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];
        if (replacements[word.trim()]) {
            words[i] = replacements[word].trim();
        }
    }

    displayElement.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
}
```

[Updated JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8k9b83mo/8/)

Comment: Wow thanks Esteban! Now you guys are just doing my work for me.